# Using GREP in TextWrangler to search all plaintext, or text outside angle brackets

Tags: grep

I'm looking for a way to search any and all plaintext appearing outside of angle brackets, to replace it with blank so that only code appearing within angle brackets remains.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the objective is to remove everything outside of the `<tags>` without affecting the `<tags>` themselves in an efficient way, inside TextWrangler. My solution is limited, in that it only matches text that is `<tags>inside the tags<tags>`. Which means that it will not remove any text that appears before or after the tags. i.e. Only text inside the tags gets removed. It is easy enough once this is done to select/delete the remaining text.

Assuming the file you want to edit is open. 
Type: "command f" to open the find window. 
Under "Find" enter `(>.*?<)`
Under "Replace" enter `><`

I would post a picture, but I'm new so not allowed.

- To see what will be replaced, click "Next".
- To replace one occurrence at a time(slow), click "Replace & Find".
- To replace all occurrences, click "Replace All"

Comment: Thanks for the response, it seems that you do understand my question, but unfortunately the suggestion did not work. To offer more clarity, I have a long list (more than 36,000 lines) of <img src="URL"> tags, with plaintext descriptors between each image. The idea is for the images to create a grid, but with all the comments separating them it is currently an ugly mess which resembles nothing close to a grid.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what it is you are trying to accomplish? When you say "the suggestion did not work", what part of the problem did it not solve? It seems that you are trying to format a large set of images for display, I'm guessing in a browser? Or is this grid something that you are displaying in Text wrangler? If you will post a small (<20) sample of your code before and after my solution is applied, I may be able to come up with something more appropriate.